# ionic 2 Blank App takes 10 Seconds to boot up why?

Tags: ionic2, delay, boot

I am working on ionic 1 but some of the dynamic functionality are not working  , like Network changes so i am thinking to jumping on Ionic 2 but when i just build the simple Blank App of ionic and installed it in my android phone it took around 13 seconds to boot up.

```
ionic start test --blank --v2
```

I use this command to download the app in ionic 2 version and then just build the app using.

```
ionic build android
```

And then I installed it in my Coolpad Note 3 Lite and on first boot it took around 13 seconds and from second boot on wards it took around 10 seconds. Is it really the case or somewhere I did mistake. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ionic build android includes debugging tools and other files to startup.

If you want to get Production/Release application, you can use

```
ionic build android --release --prod
```

for actual app, which takes maximum of 5 secs to boot.

Comment: It gave me android-release-unsigned.apk  but this apk is not installing in my coolpad note 3 lite. ** Failed to install the app **

Comment: which helps how to generate signed/release apk

Comment: After following all the steps it still gives me the same error. **Failed to install the app**

Comment: It must work, if you followed all the steps correctly. May be there are some security issues with your phone's developer options. Can you try on another phone?

Comment: Ya it worked, actually I didn't uninstalled the previous Unsigned APK. Thanks. !